# speech_recognition, Python 3.11.2

Tags: python, speech-recognition

```
import speech_recognition as sr

def noice_fix(mic):
    with mic as source:
        sr.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        while True:
            try:
                audio = sr.listen(source, timeout=0.1)
                # Check if audio loud enough
                rms = audio.rms
                if rms < 35:
                    continue  # ignore audio if too quiet
            except sr.WaitTimeoutError:
                pass
            except:
                print("Error while recording audio")
```

Problems:

```
Cannot find reference 'adjust_for_ambient_noise' in '__init__.py'
Cannot find reference 'listen' in '__init__.py'
```

This is only part of the code, but the main point is that this function would let all incoming sound through, and ignore the sound below 35 decibels in real-time

I called `speech_recognition` as `sr` but the code doesn't see that, I guess.
I tried to rename the function, and reinstall the library but it does not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

`adjust_for_ambient_noise` is a method of a `Recognizer` instance, not a function in the module. You have to create an instance of a recognizer first. Same thing goes for calling the `.listen` method.

```py
import speech_recognition as sr

recognizer = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()

...

with mic as source:
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    ...
    recognizer.listen(source)
```

You can see a working example of this in the package's `__main__.py` [on GitHub](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/8b07762f80dfec2d34fb4c40b8eddbb7ec503521/speech_recognition/__main__.py#LL8C25-L8C49), which you can try out by running the following command:  `python -m speech_recognition`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you haven't created an instance of the `Recognizer` class. Without an instance, you cannot use the `adjust_for_ambient_noise()` method. You have to create instances of the `Recognizer` and the `Microphone` classes of the speech recognition module. Modified code:

```
#Import the necessary modules
import speech_recognition as sr

#Create instances of the Recognizer and the Microphone classes
recog = sr.Recognizer()
user_mic = sr.Microphone()

def noise_fix(mic):
    with mic as source:
        recog.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        #Your other code

#Call the function
noise_fix(user_mic)
```

In the above code, we create instances of the afore mentioned classes. Then we use the instance of the `Recognizer` class to access the `adjust_for_ambient_noise()` method. At the end, we pass the instance of the `Microphone` class to the `noise_fix()` function.